# Framework for selenium

Tags: selenium, pytest

I'm new to Selenium (coming from a QTP background) and have been trying to set up my automation framework.
I'm using a modular, data driven framework, so I have classes of functions that I'm reusing (eg. a class to read values off a spreadsheet and populate a web page).

A simple test might look like:

- Log in to the system
- Check the balance
- Perform a transaction
- Check the new balance

I'll have different functions for logging in, checking the balance and performing a transaction, which I will call in my driver test. I'm using pytest to assert that the balance displayed on the screen matches the expected balance (recorded in a spreadsheet).

My question is, should I be using a framework such as Nose? "Unit testing" gets mentioned a lot in that framework, so I don't know if that is applicable to the type of testing I'm wanting to do? Does anyone have other suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: You mentioned you're using pytest which already *is* a testing framework? I'm not sure I get the question...

Comment: Sorry about the terminology. My confusion is coming in when I see examples of people using "unititest.Testcase" for example. I'm not using this for my tests, I'm not using that when executing my tests. Should I be using that? Is there some sort of standard for how Selenium pytest tests are executed?

Comment: `unittest.TestCase` is something provided by python's built-in unittest.py, which is another test framework - just like nose or pytest are. I'd recommend you continue using pytest and either [pytest-selenium](https://github.com/davehunt/pytest-selenium) or [pytest-splinter](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-splinter).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm going to read up on both of those.